# How to DXT1 compress textures?

Tags: c#, xna, compression, textures, content-pipeline

I'm currently using XNA, the problem is that the textures(.png) are using to much space, how do I "DXT1" Compress them. I have tried to find a solution but I was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean.
The XNA pipeline supports compressing Texture objects, but only if they are sized as a power of 2. (32, 64, 128, 256...)
To do this, go to your Content Project, and for each image adjusted the properties under `Content Processor`. Set `Resize to Power of Two` to be **True**, and `Texture Form` to be **DxtCompressed**.